# WordPress Rest API Cookie Authenfication

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Since the authentification documentation of the WordPress Rest API is not that helpful when it comes to a full working example i created my own fully working cookie authentification example. API calls are made with Ajax (jquery).

It would be really great if some more advanced users can give me feedback if this solution is secure enough for a production environment. (public theme)

**Lets start with the PHP**

This is how i setup a rest route with a permession callback. The callback returns true if the WP Nonce is verified.
http://pastebin.com/wATJwGmD

If the nonce is invalid the api returns a 403
http://pastebin.com/KPaLHv8V

**This is the javascript part:**

http://pastebin.com/32Xq1JkZ

The nonce is created via the localize_script function descripted here: http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/

Comment: I am not a security expert, but I have implemented WP-REST-API a few times.  Rather than create your own cookie & nonce authentication, have you looked at JSON Web Tokens?  Already live and working for example at https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, will give it a look. :)